# Finding elements inside ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is it possible to simplify the code below?

```
dynamic model = GetExpandoObject(); //model type of ExpandoObject

var result = model.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "node").Value;

if (result != null)
{
    result = ((ExpandoObject)result).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "children");

    if (result != null)
    {
        result = ((IList<object>)((KeyValuePair<string, object>)result).Value).FirstOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
        {
            if (result != null)
            {
                result = ((ExpandoObject)result).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "node").Value;

                if (result != null)
                {
                    result = ((ExpandoObject)result).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "stuff");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe it is possible to implement similar logic with Linq?  Any thoughts?

Comment: please let us know if we are on the right track here @sreginogemoh

Comment: Keep in mind that `FirstOrDefault` on an `IEnumerable` of reference types can return null.  Many of those `.Value` calls are vulnerable to `NullReferenceException`s.

Comment: `dynamic model = …;  model.FirstOrDefault(…)` How can this compile? `FirstOrDefault()` is an extension method and those don't work on `dynamic`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code, the variable result is just of type `object` because the compiler doesn't know what the result of `FirstOrDefault` is going to be.

Below I've used explicit typing using `T` for clarity and so that `var` doesn't evaluate to `object`

I created this extension method so that you wouldn't have to cast the object everytime you wanted to use it... this takes care of that before it returns

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static T FirstOrDefault<T>(this ExpandoObject eo, string key)
    {
        object r = eo.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == key).Value;
        return (r is T) ? (T)r : default(T);
    }
}
```

What follows is a re-implementation of the original post's code using the above method

```
ExpandoObject model = GetExpandoObject();

var someExpandoObject = model.FirstOrDefault<ExpandoObject>("node");
if (someExpandoObject == null) return;

var kvp = someExpandoObject.FirstOrDefault<KeyValuePair<string, object>>("children");
if (kvp.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<string, object>))) return;

var ilo = kvp.Value as IList<object>;
if (ilo == null) return;

someExpandoObject = ilo.FirstOrDefault() as ExpandoObject;
if (someExpandoObject == null) return;

someExpandoObject = someExpandoObject.FirstOrDefault<ExpandoObject>("node");
if (someExpandoObject == null) return;

object finalResult = someExpandoObject.FirstOrDefault<object>("stuff");
```

What follows is another possible implementation using nested `if` statements instead of multiple `return` statements.

```
ExpandoObject model = GetExpandoObject();

ExpandoObject someExpandoObject;
KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp;
IList<object> ilo;
object finalResult;

if ((someExpandoObject = model.FirstOrDefault<ExpandoObject>("node")) != null)
{
    if (!(kvp = someExpandoObject.FirstOrDefault<KeyValuePair<string, object>>("children")).Equals(default(KeyValuePair<string, object>)))
    {
        if ((ilo = kvp.Value as IList<object>) != null)
        {
            if ((someExpandoObject = ilo.FirstOrDefault() as ExpandoObject) != null)
            {
                if ((someExpandoObject = someExpandoObject.FirstOrDefault<ExpandoObject>("node")) != null)
                    finalResult = someExpandoObject.FirstOrDefault<object>("stuff");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update:
Using a newer feature of C# [null-propagation](https://davefancher.com/2014/08/14/c-6-0-null-propagation-operator/), we can string all these calls together. Now we no longer need to save each object down the chain (unless we want to).

Here is an implementation using null-propagation.

```
object finalResult = ((model.FirstOrDefault<ExpandoObject>("node")
    ?.FirstOrDefault<KeyValuePair<string, object>>("children").Value as IList<object>)
    ?.FirstOrDefault() as ExpandoObject)
    ?.FirstOrDefault<object>("stuff");
```

Comment: the way I understand the OP is that they want the deepest node.value that exists. your code doesn't look like it will accomplish this. but is good sounds code.

Comment: Congratulations, you've earned my last vote for the day! Good job at removing all the `if` blocks :)

Comment: @Malachi I'm not sure what the OP is trying to do exactly... a diagram of this object structure would have been helpful. I guess if he needs to go deeper he can loop :D.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks! It is shorter code, and less messy that way... as-long as he doesn't want early returns, it is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

`FirstOrDefault` *is* a LINQ extension method (see [ExpandoObject Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), so you *are* using LINQ!

@Ryan's answer looks like it's addressing the structural issue with your code, got my +1.

I'd like to add that you should **avoid reusing the same variable for a different meaning**.

It's very hard for me to tell, but it looks like the code is abusing `dynamic` - the code compiles and runs *because* the type of `result` is `dynamic` and thus resolved at run-time, and yet you're taking every opportunity at casting it back into an `ExpandoObject`, so that you get compile-time knowledge of the type you're working with.

Doing this would "cut" the `dynamic` and have `var` evaluate to `ExpandoObject` straight from the start:

```
var result = model.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "node").Value as ExpandoObject;
```

and then you could simply do:

```
if (result != null)
{
    result = result.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "children");
```

However the constant re-assignation of `result` to a different value is not helping readability, I suggest you put a meaningful name to each step.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that pops out is the repetitive calls that look like this:

> result = ((ExpandoObject)result).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "node").Value;

Which are all similar.  Half of your calls end in `.Value` and the other half don't.  Which brings up a question on my part, since I don't understand `var` in C# well enough.  So, you can put that in a separate function:

```
/**
 *  You'll have to fill in the return type and come up with a super
 * cool name.
 */
var getObj(String key)
{
    return ((ExpandoObject)result).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == key);
}

// Combine with an assignment in the condition statement, and
// you can do this:
if((result = getObj(key)) != null) { ... }
```

Upon further inspection, we can improve this slightly as well.

```
bool getObj(String key, out var result)
{
    result = ((ExpandoObject)result).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == key);
    return result != null;
}

// So you can do things like:
if(getObj(key, out result)) { ... }
```

The second thing that pops out is the quintuple nested if statement.  The rule of thumb I've heard before is to have 2-3 nested loops/ifs at most.   It looks like you're traversing an XML-like structure, in which case I would almost always go with a recursive method to find the child node you're looking for.  In my experience, you do this by passing the object to search along with a queue of nodes.  The only downside here is that you're looking for a specific piece of data in a specific place, so you have to know all of the steps to get there(which you do in this case).

```
// I'm making some assumptions here.
ExpandoObject find(Queue<String> queue, ExpandoObject tree)
{
    if(getObj(queue.Dequeue, out tree))
    {
        return find(queue, tree);
    }
    else if (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        // We couldn't find an intermediate node, so we want 
        //to return null to show our failure
        return null; 
    }
    else 
    {
        return tree; // May be null!
    }
}
```

Finally, the IList seems to get in the way.  It's unlike the other function calls you're making, because it's using the node's `Value` instead of its `Key`.  However, if we revisit our `getObj` function, we might be able to resolve that.  AS  you can see below, if we pass it a key equal to `""`, we don't look up the key, but instead set the result to the `Value` instead.

```
bool getObj(String key, out var result)
{
    if(key.Equals(""))// If there is no key, get the value
    {
        result = ((IList<object>)((KeyValuePair<string, object>)result).Value).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else // If there is a key, use it!
    {
        result = ((ExpandoObject)result).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == key);
    }
    return result != null;
}
```

Then the question becomes, how do we call all of this to make it work?  I'll start with the first line of your code:

```
dynamic model = GetExpandoObject(); //model type of ExpandoObject

Queue<String> queue;
queue.Enqueue("node");
queue.Enqueue("");
queue.Enqueue("children");
queue.Enqueue("");
queue.Enqueue("node");
queue.Enqueue("");
queue.Enqueue("stuff");

ExpandoObject result = find(queue, model);
if(result != null)
{
    // Success! do what you will with it.
}
```

And the caveat, of course, is that I can't compile any of this, run it, or verify the sanity of any of it.  At the very least, I hope it gives you some ideas or will work for you with a few tweaks.

It's my personal preference to always explicitly name the types of things in C#.  `dynamic` and `var` are wonderful and have their place, but I only use them for one-liners.  Carrying around a `var` for a long time through nested statements can be a pain to debug and maintain when you revisit this code.

Unfortunately, I don't know much about linq - well, I know it, but I haven't used it enough to have that intuition on when and how to use it really effectively - so I can't provide a solution that uses linq.

Comment: `var` has **nothing** to do with `dynamic`. `var` is simply *implicit typing* - the actual type is inferred from the type of the assignment, and that's resolved at compile-time (you get IntelliSense and can even get the IDE to tell you what `var` stands for by hovering the variable with your mouse cursor). `dynamic`, however, is resolved at run-time. **That's** something you don't want to carry around for a long time through nested statements. Using `var` has zero caveats and reduces redundant code like `MyObject foo = new MyObject()`.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks for the clarification!  I'll admit, C# is a language I only use in my spare time(and wish I could use it on the job).

Comment: Combining `bool` and `out` makes sense when the default value is also valid. But here, `null` indicates failure, so there is no reason for the separate `bool` result.

Answer (score 2):

you could make it a little less cluttered by putting the result into the if statement like this

```
dynamic model = GetExpandoObject(); //model type of ExpandoObject

var result = model.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "node").Value;

if (result = null)
{
}else{
    if(((ExpandoObject)result).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "children") = null)
    {
        //result is already what it should be.
    } else {
        if (((IList<object>)((KeyValuePair<string, object>)result).Value).FirstOrDefault() = null)
        {
            result = ((ExpandoObject)result).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "children");
        } else {
            if (((ExpandoObject)result).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "node").Value = null)
            {
                result = ((IList<object>)((KeyValuePair<string, object>)result).Value).FirstOrDefault();
            } else {
                result = ((ExpandoObject)result).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "stuff");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the innermost else statement should still check `((ExpandoObject)result).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "stuff")` for nulls depending on what you are doing with the result.  if something else checks for nulls later than I guess you shouldn't worry about it here.

the way I did it here makes sure that you are really only assigning to the variable twice at most, the first initialization of the variable and then again if there is a deeper node that needs to be assigned to it.

Comment: C# won't cast references to bool as a test-for-null: it needs explicit comparison i.e. `!= null`

Comment: @ChrisW, that should work then, you could get rid of the variable all together

Comment: And now you got caught by the reuse of `result` - it *needs* to be reassigned for it to work. This code isn't equivalent to the OP's.

Comment: I think your newer code doesn't work because, unlike the OP, each statement isn't reassigning to / reusing the result variable. In fact you're using result in your expressions but you deleted its first definition/assignment.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I was just looking at that. give me a second guys...

Comment: the result needs to be assigned at the deepest level possible. I think  rewrite is in order.

Comment: Your first answer might have been legal if instead of `if (result = expression)` you had written `if ((result = expression) != null)`.

Comment: @ChrisW, sorry I was working on changing the answer,  does this look a little better, or do I still need to change the if statements?

Comment: I think it looks worse than, and probably not the same functionality as, the OP's code.

Comment: @ChrisW it looks the same to me, except that I am not assigning to the `result` variable every step, only when I can't go any farther.

Comment: In the OP's code but not in yours, if the expression involving "node" returns null then the value in result is null. I don't much want to code review your answer in further detail.

Answer (score 1):

I would take advantage of using `dynamic`. It will throw `RuntimeBinderException` when a property doesn't exist, so you can just catch that:

```
dynamic model = GetExpandoObject();

dynamic result = null;

try
{
    result = model.node.children.node.stuff;
}
catch (RuntimeBinderException)
{
}
```

Using exceptions unnecessarily is not great, but I think it's better than your overly verbose code.